# Rust hellow-world web servers have 7-40k rps - Why?

Tags: macos, rust

I am expecting 300-500k rps with Rust. What I het is 7-40k rps.

---

I copied the hello-world example of `rocket` and `actix_web`:

rocket:

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[get("/hello/<name>/<age>")]
fn hello(name: String, age: u8) -> String {
    format!("Hello, {} year old named {}!", age, name)
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![hello]).launch();
}
```

actix_web:

```
use actix_web::{get, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};

#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[post("/echo")]
async fn echo(req_body: String) -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(req_body)
}

async fn manual_hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hey there!")
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("hi!");
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .service(hello)
            .service(echo)
            .route("/hey", web::get().to(manual_hello))
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

the results are (for actix_web):

```
$ autocannon "http://localhost:8080/" -c 10 -d 5                                        15s
Running 5s test @ http://localhost:8080/
10 connections

┌─────────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ Stat    │ 2.5% │ 50%  │ 97.5% │ 99%  │ Avg     │ Stdev   │ Max   │
├─────────┼──────┼──────┼───────┼──────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────┤
│ Latency │ 0 ms │ 0 ms │ 0 ms  │ 0 ms │ 0.01 ms │ 0.11 ms │ 13 ms │
└─────────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────┘
┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Stat      │ 1%      │ 2.5%    │ 50%     │ 97.5%   │ Avg     │ Stdev   │ Min     │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Req/Sec   │ 42527   │ 42527   │ 49375   │ 49631   │ 47817.6 │ 2710.34 │ 42503   │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Bytes/Sec │ 3.74 MB │ 3.74 MB │ 4.35 MB │ 4.37 MB │ 4.21 MB │ 238 kB  │ 3.74 MB │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

Req/Bytes counts sampled once per second.

239k requests in 5.02s, 21 MB read
```

With NodeJs, I get 30k rps. Why?

```
require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

```
 p/singer {stav/research-changes} $ autocannon "http://localhost:8080/" -c 10 -d 5                                         5s
Running 5s test @ http://localhost:8080/
10 connections

┌─────────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ Stat    │ 2.5% │ 50%  │ 97.5% │ 99%  │ Avg     │ Stdev   │ Max   │
├─────────┼──────┼──────┼───────┼──────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────┤
│ Latency │ 0 ms │ 0 ms │ 0 ms  │ 0 ms │ 0.01 ms │ 0.11 ms │ 11 ms │
└─────────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────┘
┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Stat      │ 1%      │ 2.5%    │ 50%     │ 97.5%   │ Avg     │ Stdev   │ Min     │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Req/Sec   │ 35647   │ 35647   │ 44095   │ 44351   │ 42102.4 │ 3331.11 │ 35624   │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Bytes/Sec │ 5.45 MB │ 5.45 MB │ 6.75 MB │ 6.78 MB │ 6.44 MB │ 510 kB  │ 5.45 MB │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

Req/Bytes counts sampled once per second.

210k requests in 5.01s, 32.2 MB read
```

---

```
macos 10.15.1 
rustc 1.54.0-nightly (5dc8789e3 2021-05-21)
node 14

cpu = 2%
ram = 50%
```

Note: I use `cargo run --release` to run the examples.

Comment: In addition to what kmdreko said: what Rocket version are you using? The current version on crates.io does not yet use async and cannot handle as many simultaneous connection right now. Try the `master` branch of Rocket instead.

Comment: Rocket is mentioned in the second sentence. But yes, please [edit] your question to add the exact Rocket code you used :)

Comment: @kmdreko yes. I use --release flag. same results with and without.

Comment: We can leave Rocket aside because I'm getting the same results with other framework as well. I think there is something wrong globally in my setup but im not sure what that is... rust CANT be that slow...

Comment: Not exactly what you did, but I benchmarked a hello world using rocket master with wrk and compared it to the node program you posted. I get 54k rps for node, 230k for Rocket. Can you try your programs with `wrk`?